# Simpler way of removing bad peers in go-ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum

I daily have to remove 5-15 peers that's constantly delivering stale data. I have to manually remove them with admin.removepeer() by using their enode address. Unfortunately, the go-ethereum logs only show the peer id's and not their enode address which means I have to run the admin.peers command and manually scan a large list of peers to find the corresponding enode address, which is oc both time-consuming and cumbersome. Is there a simpler way to remove bad peers for ex. with their id or something? I guess I could make a script to do it for me but I wanted to know if there's something available already that I've overlooked.

-TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Geth JavaScript Console type:

```
var _remPeerById = function(id){admin.removePeer(admin.peers.filter(x=>id===id)[0].enode)};
```

Now you can remove peers from the console using the peer ID only by calling the new *_remPeerByID* function with a peer ID like so (the peer id used here is only an example, replace with the ID of the peer you wish to remove):

```
_remPeerById("59e10c2c9a68c326511236381b84c9ec52e72ad732eb0b2")
```

, which will return *undefined* if success or an error if not found.